# Registering certain character arrays separately using Data-Structures

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

So I am trying to make a rental program that reads in a file with a list of cars ( year, make, model, price, and if available).
I also have to make options such as showing all cars and having the user look at a specific car( for example they type 1, and it will show the top car on the text file). This is where I am confused, I tried making several cars such as car1,car2, etc. But I am having trouble registering the first read car into car1.

This is an example file.

CarData.txt

```
2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 1
2012 Honda CRV 85.10 0
2015 Ford Fusion 90.89 0
2013 GMC Yukon 110.43 0
2009 Dodge Neon 45.25 1
2011 Toyota Rav4 65.02 1
2012 Mazda CX5 86.75 1
2016 Subaru Outback 71.27 0
2015 Ford F150 112.83 1
2010 Toyota Corolla 50.36 1
```

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

struct car
{
    int year;
    char make[10];
    char model[10];      
    float price;
    int available;

}car1[1], car2[1], car3[1], car4[1], car5[1], car6[1], car7[1], car8[1], car9[1], car10[1];



void copy_string(char d[][50], char s[][50]);

int my_strcmp(char *a, char *b);


 // Main Function
int main ()
{
// declare variables
int choice;
car carLib[10];
char array[30][50];
char filename[10];
ifstream carInData;


  //prompt user for input file
cout << " Enter file name: ";
cin >> filename;

cout << " 1 - Show Cars\n";
cout << " 2 - Rental Cost\n";
cout << " 3 - Most Expensive Car\n";

carInData.open(filename);

    cin >> choice;



    if(carInData.is_open());
    {
    int count = 0;
    // read list of names into array


      for( count; count < 1; count++){
    carInData >> car1[count].year >> car1[count].make >> car1[count].model >> car1[count].price >> car1[count].available; 
    carInData >> car2[count].year >> car2[count].make >> car2[count].model >> car2[count].price >> car2[count].available;


        switch (choice){
        case 1:

        cout << car1[count].year << " " << car1[count].make << " " << car1[count].model << " " << car1[count].price << " " << car1[count].available << "  " << "\n"; 
        cout << car2[count].year << " " << car2[count].make << " " << car2[count].model << " " << car2[count].price << " " << car2[count].available << "  " << "\n"; 

        break;



            }


        }
    }
  return 0;
}
// copy function
void copy_string(char d[], char s[]) {
   int c = 0;

   while (s[c] != '\0') {
      d[c] = s[c];
      c++;
   }
   d[c] = '\0';
}

// string copy
int my_strcmp(char *a, char *b)
{
    while (*a && *b && *a == *b) { ++a; ++b; }
    return *a - *b;
}
```

Comment: When dealing with strings you really should be using `std::string`.

Comment: This is 100% C, if you are actually programming in C++ please use some of the convenient library helper classes like `std::string`, `std::vector` etc.

Comment: @NathanOliver I cannot use data string types.

Comment: @GillBates I am only allowed to use these two header files and no string libraries. Only character arrays.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Another lecturer teaching C-like C++?

Comment: @GillBates That is not uncommon...

Comment: Recommending a stop and rethink on this one. Why would you want 300 `car1`s and 300 `car2`s? What's so different between `car1` and `car2` that couldn't be handled with an array of,  say, 600 `car1`s?

Comment: Stepping thought the code with [the debugger that should have come with your development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) will probably be quite educational. You'll get a first hand look at how your program will be interpreted and executed by the computer. The debugger is one of the best tools you have available (right behind the brain and the eyeball) when writing software, so the sooner you get familiar with it, the better off you'll be.

Comment: @user4581301
Ok I fixed it. And I have managed to register car1 and car2!

Comment: I would suggest to get rid of "car1" and "car2" completely, when you have the `carLib` already available to store all cars from file. During reading cars file it's possible to use some temporary `car` variable, but as you have the `carLib[]` already allocated, you can work over the next_to_be_set item, you just need some global counter to keep track of how many slots of `carLib` array are already used.

Comment: @Ped7g
That's what I was using before and it registered all the vehicles together, but that is exactly what I am confused on. I want to register the top line of the text file as car 1.

Comment: I think you really don't want to do that. That would be ultra cumbersome to use later. ... I will probably create some short answer with some examples, but not going to fix whole mess of yours, it's too ugly, sorry (at least indent properly).

Comment: extending on@Ped7g 's suggestion, say you declare `car carLib[10]`. That's ten cars. `car1` would be `carLib[0]`. `car2` is `carLib[1]`, etc.... This allows you to make a really simple loop similar to what you had initially. eg: `cin >> carLib[count].year >> carLib[count].make >> ...`

Comment: @user4581301
Wow, that makes things really simple. Thanks!

Comment: The dangers here are if you are given more than 10 cars (buffer overflow) or the name of a car is longer than 9 letters. (also a buffer overflow) This is why the real world uses `std::string` and `std::vector` Both resize to fit your needs (right up until you run out of RAM, that is).

Comment: I know for sure that the files that will be used to test my program will be exactly as mine, just with different make, models and price.

@user4581301

Comment: Count the letters in "Toyota Tacoma". This will do bad things in a 10 character array. Two things you need to know: 1. a `char` array string has no idea how much of the array is in use, so you have to mark the end of the string with a special character, a NULL. so if you have a ten character array, the most you can put in it is 9 characters because you always need one character for the "NULL terminator".

Comment: 2. reading in a string with >> will stop reading at the first whitespace character (space, tab, end of line, etc...) so if you `cin >> astring`, and the input is "Toyota Tacoma", only "Toyota" is read into `astring` "Tacoma" will be read by the next `>>`, and if the next is `cin >> anumber`, "Tacoma" isn't a number and bad things will happen that you'll need [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) and [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to get out of.

Comment: @user4581301 he reads that content as two char[10] arrays, so he fits (barely). And the terminator of C strings is zero, not NULL. The usual `#define NULL 0` is not even guaranteed IIRC, although I didn't see any platform breaking it ever. That said, in the `copy_string` function he does use quite complicated way to write zero char value: `'\0'`. But in cmp implementation he does use the short `*a` test for non-zero value... I wonder how much of that the OP fully understands and realizes how it really works. :)

Comment: @Ped7g I see your point. I used NULL instead of `NULL` for that reason, but to a new SO user that distinction might as well not exist. I should have gone with lowercase to make the distinction really stand out. Regardless, it is still called a null terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example source, how to work with array of struct type, like `car carLib[300];`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct car
{
    int year;
    char make[10];
    char model[10];     // that's only 9 letters for zero-terminated strings
    float price;
    int available;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t maxCarLib = 300;
    car carLib[maxCarLib];      // array of memory reserved for several cars
    size_t carLibCount = 0;     // current allocation of array (zero cars entered)

    carLib[carLibCount++] = car {1993, {"Nohda"}, {"XYZ"}, 123.45, 0};
    carLib[carLibCount++] = car {1994, {"Frod"}, {"Peon"}, 543.21, 1};
    carLib[carLibCount++] = car {1977, {"Nohda"}, {"ABC"}, 3.32, 0};

    std::cout << "Cars in library: " << carLibCount << std::endl;
    for (size_t carIndex = 0; carIndex < carLibCount; ++carIndex) {
        const car & carI = carLib[carIndex];
        printf("Car at index %lu: %d %s %s %f %d\n",
            carIndex, carI.year, carI.make, carI.model, carI.price, carI.available);
    }

    // Find most expensive car
    float mostExpensivePrice = 0;               // most expensive price found
    size_t mostExpensiveIndex = carLibCount;    // index points beyond array ("no car")
    for (size_t carIndex = 0; carIndex < carLibCount; ++carIndex) {
        if (carLib[carIndex].price <= mostExpensivePrice) continue;
        // the car at carIndex is more expensive than old maximum, remember it
        mostExpensivePrice = carLib[carIndex].price;
        mostExpensiveIndex = carIndex;
    }

    if (mostExpensiveIndex == carLibCount) {
        std::cout << "Most expensive car not found." << std::endl;
    } else {
        const car & carI = carLib[mostExpensiveIndex];
        printf("Most expensive car at index %lu: %d %s %s %f %d\n",
            mostExpensiveIndex, carI.year, carI.make, carI.model, carI.price, carI.available);
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/2r7cx)

Mind you, this is just array indexing example, this "old C" code style is very error prone to index-out-of-bounds code, overwriting memory, or accessing wrong memory. That's why in modern C++ you can use `std::vector<car> carLib;` instead, which is much better fit for such task.

Vector example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct car
{
    int year;
    char make[10];
    char model[10];     // that's only 9 letters for zero-terminated strings
    float price;
    int available;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<car> carLib;

    carLib.push_back(car {1993, {"Nohda"}, {"XYZ"}, 123.45, 0});
    carLib.push_back(car {1994, {"Frod"}, {"Peon"}, 543.21, 1});
    carLib.push_back(car {1977, {"Nohda"}, {"ABC"}, 3.32, 0});

    std::cout << "Cars in library: " << carLib.size() << std::endl;
    for (const auto & kar : carLib) {
        printf("%d %s %s %f %d\n",
            kar.year, kar.make, kar.model, kar.price, kar.available);
    }

    if (0 < carLib.size()) {
        // indexing trough size_t index still possible with vector
        std::cout << "Last car price is: " <<
            carLib[carLib.size()-1].price << std::endl;
        // Last valid index being size()-1, because first index is 0
    }
}
```

But that C-like is good for you to study details about computer memory, also it does introduce you to the "`float` is not a good variable type for amounts", as the live demo shows. So open it in debugger, and find some memory window, and study how the data are actually laid out in memory, how 10 letter long name of car makes your struct problematic, etc...

The `std::vector` stores the struct in the same way as the bare array, only having few more helper data around, and reserving the memory dynamically as you need, so understanding the array example (and it's shortcomings) first is just as important.

Comment: Might as well go full C++ and replace the `printf`s with `std::cout`, at least for the second example..

Comment: @user4581301: I did try, but the `cout` is so clumsy when it gets to the formatting, I still prefer `printf` even in my production code, reads better than the stream stuff to me. And writes much better.